# I need Excel Formul. List and filter

Tags: excel

[how many HASAN KIVILCIM worked 12.05.2018(total)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmRi0.png)

Comment: Look at SUMIFS using HASAN KIVILCIM and 12.05.2018

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"HASAN KIVILCIM",A:A,DATEVALUE("12/05/2018"))
```